# How to have database tables to show 'You liked this' for a user, on a page which has list of post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

There is a page on which posts are listed. For a logged in user, what is the best way to keep tables in database which can be helpful to show 'You liked this' on the posts which he has liked.
It is similar to how facebook show 'You Like this' on the feed which user already liked.

Comment: i think this gem https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable will end your search

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is,

Create new table `Like(user_id,post_id,liked)`

Use this table to track user likes.

**Edit:**

If you want to get all query in one query, use serialize

Table will be `Like(user_id,status(type should be :text))`

in Like model

```
 serialize :status
```

Use this like,

```
like = Like.new
like.user = user
like.status = {liked: post.id}
like.save
```

See more about serialise [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Saving+arrays,+hashes,+and+other+non-mappable+objects+in+text+columns)

Comment: I created that only. But when 50+ posts are listed on page, then querying for each post will be too much load on server & latency on client. Can the table be made such that it can be achieved in 1 query?

Answer (score 0):

Create a HABTM relation between Post and User, you can even call the table "likes" if you want to. Then you will have `@post.users` which will list users who liked this post, and `@user.post`s which will list posts that the user has liked.
A Join table is meaningless in this situation, you do not need any extra fields besides the two foreign keys.

Also 50+ posts should not create any kind of load on your server. The amount of data is very very small. More likely the issue is in your rendering, not in the backend portion of the code. And yes, you can get the info in one query by eager loading or preloading the join table during querying for posts. Something along the lines of `Post.includes(:users)` or
`Post.eager_load(:users)`

Comment: I didn't get what exactly you wanted to say.What i did is created a Like(user_id, post_id) table. The latency/load i am talking about is 50+ queries on server for each post and finding out if current_user has liked it or not. The relation i am using is Like-> belong_to user, post. post-> HM Likes, User -> HM Likes

Comment: What you did is exactly what I was trying to tell you not to do. You do not need an extra table with a model and has_many :through relations. You can do this with just has_and_belongs_to_many and a join table without a model.

Comment: Can you explain more about your solution. I understood about habtm relationship, but how to use it effectively is my doubt

Comment: What do you mean how to use it effectively? Doing post.users i.e querying over the HBTM relationship gives you a list of users who have liked this post. Doing user.posts gives you all the posts this user has liked. This is as efficient as it can be.